# WritableBitmap: Memory allocation mismatch - How to solve?

Tags: wpf, writablebitmap

In my program I try to read a color palette image's ([`FormatConvertedBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap) with format `Indexed4`) pixels using a [`WritableBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap).

The dimensions of the resulting image are 20 * 27 pixels.

The color palette is 16 colors, so each color takes a nibble and each byte carries two pixels.

However, in memory, WPF adds an additional DWORD to the end of each pixel row:

[image: WPF WritableBitmap memory allocation]

I'm not able to address particular pixels with this mismatch.

What BitmapSource property do I need to examine to be able to compute the correct stride of this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WPF BitmapSource may use whatever stride it prefers, provided that it can hold the values of all pixels in a row. In particular, it may adjust the stride for whatever kind of optimized memory access.

The size of the underlying buffer is calculated by multiplying the stride with the number of rows:

```
WritableBitmap bitmap = ...
var bufferSize = bitmap.BackBufferStride * bitmap.PixelHeight;
```